# Domain too many redirection

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Hi after 1 week of research i'm still stuck with my domain redirections
I want my http://domain.fr pointing to https://www.domain.fr
I'm trying with htaccess file with no success...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.*
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When i'm testing my redirections it seems https://www.domain.fr is redirecting itself without understading why...
have you guys any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your 2nd RewriteRule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.*
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You rule  does a permanent redirection of `www` domain to the same location ie : ( `www.e ample.com => www.example.com` ) that is why you got the redirect loop error.

To redirect http urls to https ,first of all you need to check if the request scheme is http.  You can use `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` to check the non - secure `http` connection and then use `RewriteRule` to redirect the request to `https` .

Use the following simple Rule to redirect `http` to `https` :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: Still not working... I think the problem comes from SSL Gateway which deliverate my SSL certificate they must be doing some redirections too... Thank for your explication about htaccess